# How to make my three table sql join work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i am working on a project. and i am trying to query three table through `INNER JOIN`..But it i not working..So i want to expose the issue to you..so somebody could help..here is how i design my db

**items table**

```
id_item(PK, autoincrement) item_name (char, 100) item_price(char,10)
  1                         nike                  12000
```

**groupe table**

```
id_groupe (PK, autoincrement) groupe_name (char, 100)
  1                             homme
```

**color table**

```
id_color (PK, autoincrement) name_color(char, 30)
  1                           white
```

**item_groupe**

```
it_ID (PK)  groupeid(PK)
 1           1
```

**item_color**

```
itemId(PK) colorId(PK)
 1           1
```

So, I want to achieve is to query the tables to sort out the following information about the item:
`the item name, item price and item color`. So I run the follwoing sql query.

```
$sql ="SELECT items.id_item,item_name FROM items INNER JOIN item_color ON item_color.itemId=items.id_item INNER JOIN color ON color.id_color = item_color.colorId INNER JOIN
    item_groupe ON item_groupe.it_ID = id_item INNER JOIN groupe ON item_groupe.groupeid = groupe.id_groupe WHERE id_groupe =1";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Can somebody help!

Comment: Char 100? Surely VARCHAR. And might price assume a numeric data type

Comment: Your query seems to work? -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78b9f/2/0 -- the only think I might have changed was naming the first table "items" which matched your query but not the problem statement.

Comment: @bd808 the color name(white) appears in your query result?

Comment: @kbadevelopeur Ah. Besides assuming the proper table name was "items" I also added `name_color` to the field list of the select statement ("SELECT items.id_item,item_name,name_color FROM ...")

Answer (score 0):

Dive into this snippet:

```
SELECT i.item_name AS name, i.item_price AS price, c.name_color AS color
FROM items i
  JOIN item_color ic ON i.id_item = ic.itemId
  JOIN color c ON ic.colorid = c.id_color
  /*next two joins are necessary to filter item by group*/
  JOIN item_groupe ig ON i.id_item = ig.it_ID
  JOIN groupe g ON ig.groupeid = g.id_groupe
/*example of filtering product by name*/
WHERE g.id_groupe = 1
```

[Full example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/410c1/4).

P.S. Your naming conventions are so messy :)