# SQL query to make the code work to join three tables

Tags: sql

My code is not working and I am not sure how to fix it to make it work properly. And yes [How to make my three table sql join work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850074/how-to-make-my-three-table-sql-join-work) did not work for me.

```
SELECT [id], 
review.[plot_name], 
submission.[sub_date],
[report_date], report.[critical_errors]
FROM ((review
INNER JOIN submission ON review.[id] = submission.[id])
INNER JOIN report ON [id] = report.[id])
WHERE [plot_name] = Scheme;
```

Comment: You have instances of [id] that don’t include the table name

Comment: never include "did not work for me." in a question, and always copy/paste the complete error message.  Also only ask when you did a search for that error message. And, you should specify which database system you are using. SQL is behaves different on different systems like MSSQL, MySQL, MariadDB, PostgreSQL, SQLite, ...etc

Comment: In other words, the pattern of a useful SQL question normally is to provide `Create Table` statements of the involved ones, namely "review", "submission", and "report" in your case and a few Test Data rows provided as `Insert Into` statements, that the readers can run in order to help you, and a description of the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NickW said, you'll need to tell the RDBMS which [ID] in your statement belongs to what table, same for any other column names that would occur in more than one of the involved tables. And you can tell us the make and model of your RDBMS by adding a Tag like `postgresql-9.3` for example. And as @Luuk pointed out, you may want to explain what "does not work" in your scenario exactly means, for example by describing the desired result when you run your statement against certain test data rows.

Your attempt so far looks as if you perhaps want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE review (reviewID Int, plot_name Char(20));
CREATE TABLE submission (submissionID Int, reviewID Int, sub_date Date);
CREATE TABLE report (reportID Int, reviewID Int, report_date Date, critical_errors Char(20));

INSERT INTO review VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'Scheme'),  (4, 'Scheme');
INSERT INTO submission VALUES (1, 3, Cast('2022, 2, 25' as Date));
INSERT INTO report VALUES (2, 3, Cast('2022-3-25' as Date), 'not so critical');

SELECT
    review.reviewID, review.plot_name,
    submission.sub_date, 
    report.report_date, report.critical_errors 
FROM review
    INNER JOIN submission ON review.reviewID = submission.reviewID 
    INNER JOIN report ON review.reviewID = report.reviewID
WHERE review.plot_name = 'Scheme';
```

[Expected Result:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=24ffe3c034687fe6723ca3a5381a938e)

```
|ReviewId  | plot_name | sub_date | report_date | critical_errors |
|----------|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|
|   3      |'Scheme'   |02/25/2022| 03/25/2022  |'not so critical'|
```

---

NB: ReviewID #4 not being in the result because the Inner Join tables intentionally have no primary/foreign key matches.

Comment: Somehow my "Expected result" formatting attempt looks good to me in Edit mode, but awfully bad in View mode?

Comment: I tried updating  the expected result as well, but for reason that I don't seem to understand it won't show in View mod, so I made it as code instead. At least it looks a little nicer